# Share variable in web.config Across Projects in a Solution in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have one solution that contains 3 projects :  ASP.net MVC 4.0, Share Library and Web Service project. I want to share some of key value in appSettings of Web.Config in ASP.net mvc Project to Web Service Project. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007572/is-it-possible-to-share-the-web-config-across-multiple-projects-in-a-solutiona) but it's now working for me.

Could anyone give me some idea please.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Put the key in all config files?

Comment: All the keys, I keep it in config file of my project. Then I want to take it to use in another project.

Answer (score 0):

You could store that information into a dll that you would share accross all your projects :

Create a new Class Library project :

Name your class MyConfiguration.cs for example

```
namespace CentralizedInformation
{
    public static class MyConfiguration
    {
        public static string Value1 = "Test string value 1";
        public static int Value2 = 2;
    }
}
```

After you can add the reference in all your projects (Project -> add reference -> Browse -> Browse to CentralizedInformation.dll)

and add itin your projects (here an mvc project example)

```
using CentralizedInformation;

//for asp net mvc project 
protected void Application_Start()
{
   string mySharedAccrossAllProjectsString = CentralizedInformation.MyConfiguration.Value1;
   //put it wherever you need it session or anything else
}
```

Juste reference the same in your other projects and you are done. Also rebuild your projects when you want to update the data ...

That dll could have a config file and you could programmatically expose all it's data.

I admit it's a quite funny and complicated way to do such a simple thing. But that's a way ^^

Comment: Thanks Arno2501. What I want to do, is not take the variable that set in the class like `Value1`, `Value2` that u implement above, But I want to take the variable from Web.Config of my asp.net mvc project.

Comment: Oh ok in that case I would suggest you implement a controller in your mvc project that access your web.config. Then you can stream it to whatever project / application as long as it can use WebClient.

Comment: Arno2501 : Stream it? how could I do that?

Comment: Well stream it as a file or exposing it's properties (of the web.config file)

Comment: You could do that thru a controller of your actual MVC Project