# How to best manage shared app config contents among projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration, web-config, app-config

I have one back-end DLL project, which is layer on top of database. I have several fron-end projects, with either app.config or web.config. All front-end projects share some configuration sections.

Manually keeping the shared config sections in sync before testing and release looks stupid. What is good practice to get the config shared?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007572/is-it-possible-to-share-the-web-config-across-multiple-projects-in-a-solutiona

Comment: @PaoloCosta Thanks, but it is a bit different and the original question is not answered well. I want to share some sections only, not entire config file. Something like #include <header.xml>

Comment: You can put single sections in separate files

Comment: @PaoloCosta good news! Do you have link of tutorial? That would be fantastic.

Comment: You can see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your common section in a separate file:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config"/>
```

and ConnectionStrings.config file will contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=address;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then, in order to share the settings between multiple projects you can follow the advice you find [here](http://raghurana.com/blog/?p=202)