# Multiple applications and single web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web-config, machine.config

Is it possible to have single web.config file for multiple asp.net web applications?

One solution is to read web.config as text file from all applications and get the required key after parsing but it doesn't look very neat. Plus it may not work in case web.config entries are encrypted using aspnet_regiis.

Or may be the other way is to add entries in machine.config (connection strings, app settings) from where all applications can read?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. As best to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Solution as per following post is very simple and i.e. put web.config on root of wwwroot folder and every application deployed in this folder will be able to read it.

[Is it possible to share the web.config across multiple projects in a solution?(ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007572/is-it-possible-to-share-the-web-config-across-multiple-projects-in-a-solutiona)