# Using web.config of API instead of application's one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I'm working on a web application and I have 3 projects: an ASP.NET Web API, an ASP.NET MVC and an unit test project.
I want to do a connection with sqlserver database in the web.config and it works only with the application's one. But it's better if i do the connection in the api's web.config.
I think the web app doesn't care about web.config in the API but I have my DatabaseConnection.cs in the API so I don't understand why it's looking for the config file in an other project.

**DatabaseConnection.cs :**

```
    public class ApiDatabaseConnection
    {

    string connectionPath = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databaseConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connectionToSql;

    public SqlConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        connectionToSql = new SqlConnection(connectionPath);

        try
        {
            connectionToSql.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return connectionToSql;
    }
```

**Web.config :**

```
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="databaseConnection" />
<add name="databaseConnection" connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**I also tried with this :**

```
Configuration rootWebConfig1 = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Web.config");
        if (rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
        {
            KeyValueConfigurationElement customSetting = rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings["customsetting1"];
            if (customSetting != null)
                Debug.WriteLine("customsetting1 application string = \"{0}\"", customSetting.Value);
            else
                Debug.WriteLine("No customsetting1 application string");
        }
```

It only see web.config of the application, not the API's one.

Comment: What's the "API" project type? An ASP.NET project? A Class library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to share the web.config across multiple projects in a solution?(ASP.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007572/is-it-possible-to-share-the-web-config-across-multiple-projects-in-a-solutiona)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It's an empty ASP.NET web app project with Web API references
@ MajidParvin I will try this solution but i don't think it can help me because the API must have the connection. So i can use the API project later for another app if I want but i will try

Comment: Are you starting both projects when debugging the solution? Do you have the connectionstring on the web.config of the web app or the web api?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I think yes, the api is using if that you want to know. I have it on both but there is only the app's one works. When I remove connectionstring in this, it doesn't work with the web.config in the api.

Comment: The **code** you use to get the connection string from the web.config, is on the Web App, the Web Api or both?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Only on the web api, but it calls web.config on the web app project

Comment: You can try putting a random connection string on the api's web.config and calling WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings on the api's **startup**/**global.asax.cs** class, at that point the correct web.config should be gathered, if you have your files correctly structured

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto  "calling WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings on the api's startup**/**global.asax.cs class" I don't understand what I'm suppose to do with the global.asax.cs file.

Comment: Try to call WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings there

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Never used this so I find "Application["connection"] = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databaseConnectionApi"].ConnectionString;" and put in Application_Start() method in Global.asax.cs . Then I call Application["connection"].ToString() in my file but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the project structure?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i.stack.imgur.com/xS0Ri.png APIGeneSII is my api project and GeneSII, the web app.